# Load bus definitions in function's scope

Tags: matlab, simulink

How do I use `Simulink.Bus.createMATLABStruct` inside a function? I'm loading some bus definitions in the function's scope but `createMATLABStruct` doesn't see those. If I load the bus definitions in the global workspace then the function works.

Doesn't work:

```
function test()
load('someBuses.mat');
s = Simulink.Bus.createMATLABStruct('aBus');
end
```

Works:

```
load('someBuses.mat');
% ...
function test()
s = Simulink.Bus.createMATLABStruct('aBus');
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Simulink.Bus.createMATLABStruct` accepts a 4th (undocumented) input -- open the file in the editor to see the 4th input -- which can either be 'base' (the default) or a Data Dictionary object.

The default is 'base', which is why the version you have that loads from the Base Workspace works.
Have a look at this link to find out about creating [Data Dictionaries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/what-is-a-data-dictionary.html).